# Laravel TNTSearch keyword matchings

Tags: laravel, keyword, fuzzy-search, laravel-scout

Using Laravel TNTSearch how can I define different cases for keywords to end up with the same result on query.

Having the following keyword `Softwareentwickler` I want to be able to get the same result on `Software-Entwickler` keyword as well.

Is there any workaround for this case?

Answer (score 1):

The technique you want is called query expansion. What you have to do is simply replace the query with the one you want and perform the search.

Take a look at [this](https://airports.tnt.studio/tnt-analytics/query/expansions)

Here, when someone searches for `Russia` it will replace the query with `russian federation`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! In this case both of the keywords will be kept for data query? I mean can happen that some of the titles are marked as `Software-Entwickler`.

Comment: You can customize it to your needs. Either you can fully replace it or you can attach to it.

Comment: and would I implement for my model this kind of expansion?  As I see that dashboard is a paid feature.

Comment: drop us an email and we could arrange a 50% discount for you, to test the dashboard a little bit